# Does deleting a provisioning profile from the portal cause an app to expire?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, itunes

We have an app that we have distributed to employees using an ad hoc provisioning profile.

We now have a business requirement to delete the provisioning profile from the provisioning portal (though it will stay on the devices).

I am under the impression that when using ad hoc distribution, there is a periodic check done with Apple's servers (although I believe that this is checking the validity of the profile stored on the device against the certificate stored on the server, and shouldn't be affected by any changes on the provisioning profile unless the certificate is revoked, right?).

My question is:-

**Will deleting the ad hoc provisioning profile from our Provisioning Portal cause the app to stop running on the employees' devices?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not happening. The profile is only checked on install, there is no way to "revoke" a profile like with certificates. So the app will still work and can be installed using the old profile file.